# Referring to the repository url in package.json in a script

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

As usual in my package.json file I have my repository url defined:

```json
{
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "http://my.git.repo"
    }
}
```

I am trying to define a script that will push to my repo and push tags. Usually something like this would do the trick:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "push": "git push origin && git push origin --tags"
    }
}
```

but we work with pull requests and for us `origin` is our private fork. `public` is usually the public repo but this can't be relied upon. I want my push script to always push to the public repo:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "push": "git push http://my.git.repo && git push http://my.git.repo --tags"
    }
}
```

but this involves duplicating the repo url and when people copy this seed project they will forget to update the url in all 3 places. I want to refer to the url of the repo that is already specified in the package.json

I have tried something along the lines of this:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "push": "git push $npm_package_repository_url && git push $npm_package_repository_url --tags"
    }
}
```

based on this webpage: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars but it doesn't work.

Many thanks

Comment: The syntax `$npm_package_repository_url` will work fine on Mac OS X/Linux (bash), however  `%npm_package_repository_url%`  is required for Windows. You could try utilizing [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) to enable one script syntax (i.e. `$npm_package_repository_url`) to work cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

> The syntax `$npm_package_repository_url` will work fine on Mac OS X/Linux (bash), however `%npm_package_repository_url%` is required for Windows. You could try utilizing [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) to enable one script syntax (i.e. `$npm_package_repository_url`) to work cross-platform.

Thanks to RobC for this